# Using a third party SDK with React + Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, sdk, redux-saga

I am working with React + Redux application that uses a third party SDK to connect to a websocket, authenticate with a service, and send and receive data. Here are some examples of what might be done with the SDK:

```
import SDK from 'third-party';

const client = SDK.init(...);

client.connect();

client.on('auth-challenge', callback => {
    // Retrieve auth token from back-end
});

client.on('ready', () => {
    client.loadData().then(data => {
        // do something with this
    });
});
```

Might it be possible to store this data in my Redux store, or to load the auth token using Sagas and take an action on the SDK once the data is available?

I can imagine that I could import my store into this file and use `store.dispatch()` to, for example, request a token (via Saga), but how do I know when that token has loaded? Is this something that I simply need to make direct API calls with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to put the async part as a promise into the `componentDidMount` method of one of the connected components and call the dispatcher as the token is received.

```
import { askForToken } from '../my-helpers/sdk-helper;

class SomeParentComponentsContainer extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
     const { dispatch } = this.props;
     dispatch({ type: 'GET_TOKEN' })
     // async part. Drop it if you use sagas.
     askForToken()
     .then(token => {
        dispatch({ type: 'GET_TOKEN__SUCCESS', payload: { token } })
      })
     // ----
  }

  someMethodWhichNeedsTheToken = () => {
     // this is available in any connected component now from store
     const { sdkToken } = this.props;
     ....
  }

  ...
}

const mapDispatchToProps = state => ({
  sdkToken: state && state.sdkToken
})

export default connect(mapDispatchToProps)(SomeParentComponentsContainer);
```

Second option is if you use sagas, just keep `dispatch({ type: 'GET_TOKEN' })` part in `componentDidMount` and saga will do the rest.

**sagas.js**

```
import { call, put, takeEvery, takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import { askForToken } from '../my-helpers/sdk-helper;

function* fetchToken(action) {
   try {
      const user = yield call(askForToken);
      yield put({type: "GET_TOKEN__SUCCESS", token });
   } catch (e) {
      yield put({type: "GET_TOKEN__FAILS", message: e.message});
   }
}


function* mySaga() {
  yield takeEvery("GET_TOKEN", fetchToken);
}
```

See [sagas documentation](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga#mainjs) on how to set up the middleware to make saga work.

Comment: This isn't really the pattern typically seen when using redux-saga. But based on my attempts and this answer I'm thinking I do probably need to break the pattern a bit if I'm going to get this done in a reasonable way.

Comment: I completed my answer with the saga way.

Comment: Looks great. Thank you!